# How do I save all the draws from a MCMC posterior distribution to a file in R

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm running a Hierarchical Lin Regr model using `bayesm` package in R. I have a data set with one dependent and 6 predictors. There are 207 unique respondents with 35 observations for each.

I began by using

```
print(out$betadraw)
```

Then I read about the `sink` function to output the `out$betadraw` to a file. I thought that `sink` function would capture all the draws. Instead the draws were truncated after certain number of draws.

I need to capture all the draws. In addition, is it possible to pass objects from `bayesm` package to `coda` package for convergence diagnostics? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it's hard to know for sure what is going on.

You should be able to open a text connection using [?file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) with the `open` argument set to `write`.  Then, you can capture output and write it to your file using [?write](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/write.html) with the `append` argument set to `TRUE`.  The following worked fine on my machine:

```
> zz <- file(description="some name.txt", open="w")
> isOpen(zz)
[1] TRUE
> for(i in 1:100000){
+   x <- rbeta(1000, shape1=10, shape2=10)
+   write(x, file=zz, append=TRUE)
+ }
> close(zz)
```

(*Note, I wouldn't try running that; it took nearly a half an hour and created a 962 MB file that could only be opened with EditPad.*)

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I will share the data set and my code later today. In the mean time I will also try your solution and see what happens.

Comment: You're welcome, @SriKowtha. If this does resolve your issue you may want to *accept* it by clicking the check mark to the left under the vote total.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it worked. I did accept your sulution as an answer too. Thank you!